# Is "state" used as an adverb in expressions like "to state claim the region's natural resources"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

This is a sentence in CNN student news, September 02, 2015:

> There's an international race to **state** claim the region's natural resources.

Its meaning as a whole is of no confusion, but the use of the word "state" seems tricky. Is "state" used as an adverb here? I looked it up in dictionaries for all parts of speech only to find noun, verb and adjective.

How to explain such usage grammatically? Can "state" be used as an adverb?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Was this "Student News" directed to an English speaking country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"State claim" is a common error. The correct term is "stake claim" or "stake a claim". State is not used as an adverb, though in this instance many will be unaware of their <s>mistate</s> mistake.

A grammatically correct way to write the sentence would be:

> There's an international race to stake a claim in the region's natural resources.

Comment: It still seems not right if "stake claim" or "stake a claim" is put in this sentence?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that. In this particular sentence, you would need to write "stake a claim in". I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: I see the update. That really makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: one more question, in your view, is this a common mistake made by many unaware native speakers ?

Comment: @dennylv: Perhaps. They don't quite understand the meaning or origin of the original phrase. Then they don't quite hear one of the words correctly and mistake it for a different word. It's why English speakers sometimes say "for all intensive purposes" rather than "for all intents and purposes." :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say they meant:

> There's an international race to state **their** claim *to* the region's natural resources.

*their* being implied. Possibly the phrase had to fit in two lines.